# Wordpress index.php dando erro com a sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress, índices

Estou fazendo um template do zero com os conhecimentos básicas que tenho em html e css, porém estou tendo alguns contra tempos como esse:
https:// overlove.000webhostapp. com/blog

Eu ja revisei tudo e todas as formas e não encontro o erro de forma alguma. O arquivo functions.php está normal e o Index.php também... Se alguém souber me responder eu agradeço.

index.php

```
<div class="container">
<?php if(have_posts()): ?>
<?php  while(have_posts()):the_post(); ?>

       <div class="sidebar"> 
            <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar01') ?>
       </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h2>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="title" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h2>

        <div class="thumbnail">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array('911, 120')); ?>
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <div class="description"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div><br/>

        <div class="readmore">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >Continuar Lendo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="author_public">
            <publiclado>Publicado</publiclado> em <?php the_date("j/m/Y"); ?> <publiclado>Por:</publiclado> <?php the_author(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
<?php
    endwhile;
    else:
?>
<div class="no-post" >Nenhum post encontrado!</div>
<?php
    endif;
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Functions.php

```
<?php
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'=>'sidebar01',
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '<li class="widget">',
        'after_widget' => '</li>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title' => '</h4>',
    ));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'=>'sidebaranimes',
        'id' => 'sidebar-2',
        'before_widget' => '<li class="widget">',
        'after_widget' => '</li>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title' => '</h4>',
    ));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'=>'sidebaranimes2',
        'id' => 'sidebar-3',
        'before_widget' => '<li class="widget">',
        'after_widget' => '</li>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title' => '</h4>',
    ));

    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) ); 
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 911, 120, true );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Onde está:

```
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
```

Deveria ser:

```
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>'
```

Ou seja, você está fechando a tag de título errada e está incluindo uma vírgula no último elemento, quando não deveria ter.

Comment: Sim, agora percebi... Falta de atenção. Mas em relação virgula, o tutorial da wordpress tem.. https:// codex.wordpress. org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar  Mas de qualquer forma, com ou sem virgula e agr que fechei o título certo, não mudou em nada. Obrigado.